# Retrofit returns content length 0 with spring data rest

Tags: heroku, spring-boot, retrofit2

I am using spring boot application with spring data rest deployed on heroku. I have a /api/userDatas end point on which an entity can be created by a POST request. I have tested it using Postman and it gets created.

Now I am using retrofit on android to perform the same functionality. But the problem is that entity gets created on the server but onFailure() always gets called. I have debugged and found that content-length is always 0.

CreateUser

```
private void createUser() {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();

        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(logging).build();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(ServeNetworking.ServeURLS.getBaseURL())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();


        ServeNetworking serveNetworking = retrofit.create(ServeNetworking.class);
        Call<UserData> getUserByIdResponseCall = serveNetworking.socialConnectAPI(userData);
        getUserByIdResponseCall.enqueue(new Callback<UserData>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<UserData> call, Response<UserData> response) {
                Log.d("getUserById", "onResponse");
                Toast.makeText(OTPVerificationActivity.this, "userId : onResponse", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                /**
                 * Save data in local db and navigate to map screen.
                 */

                ActivityAnimationUtils.presentActivity(OTPVerificationActivity.this, MapActivity.class);

                try{
                    DBManager.getDBManager(OTPVerificationActivity.this).setIsVerified(true);
                } catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<UserData> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("getUserById", "onFailure");
                Utils.showSnackBar(OTPVerificationActivity.this,"Somethign went wrong", root);
            }
        });
    }
```

and interface:

```
public interface ServeNetworking {

    @POST("/api/userDatas")
    @Headers({ "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8"})
    Call<UserData> socialConnectAPI(
            @Body UserData user
    );

    @GET("/api/userDatas/{userId}")
    @Headers({ "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8"})
    Call<UserData> getUser(
            @Path("userId") String userId
    );


    /**
     * this class is used to get the donor base urls...
     */
    class ServeURLS{
        private static String baseURL="https://fabrimizer-serve.herokuapp.com";

        public static String getBaseURL() {
            return baseURL;
        }

    }
}
```

I am getting following error:

```
java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 1 path $
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.

added Accept header in ServeNetworking:

```
@POST("/api/userDatas")
    @Headers({ "Content-Type: application/json,"Accept: application/json"})
    Call<UserData> socialConnectAPI(
            @Body UserData user
    );
```